# <a href> is not loading the page properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="expander-demo" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Snap! the overstrained line sagged down in one long festoon; the tugging log was gone.</p>
    <a href="index2.html" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b moreinfo">More Info..</a>
</div>
```

This `<a href="index2.html">` is not loading the page correctly. Once I press the link **More Info** the actions for the page `index2.html` is not taking place. If I refresh the page again the actions are correctly taking place.

*Why is this happening?*

**index2.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Third Page</title>
<meta charset="iso-8859-15">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- jQuery and jQuery mobile -->

<script src="js/jquery_2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery_mobile_1.4.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.swiper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-swipeleft="Pages/page1.html">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>jQuery Simple Swiper Plugin Example</h1>
</div>
<!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content"><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<br>
<br>
<div align="center"> Swipe the page to see it in action.</div> </div>
<!-- /content --> 

</div>
<!-- /page -->
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the page is not loaded correctly?

Comment: what are "the actions"? can you show us some code from index2.html?

Comment: Do you refer to jQuery by 'actions' in the index2.html? If so, the jQuery might be fired already before the page is being loaded..

Comment: have you got a jsfiddle

Comment: jquery is not loading properly.

Comment: i have added the index2.html code.

Comment: try `google-analytics` script in the head ... not in body

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you fix the problem but, maybe try wrapping your jQuery in this.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       //your code here
});
```

Comment: PS can anyone tell me how to comment out code on here?

Comment: I am not getting it properly.

Comment: You comment out code as you would in the programming language.

//your code here

Answer (score 0):

Your url change in javascript , or browse cache, you can try test full url include **host/index2.html**,delete Browser's Cache or view html source generate by Browser or add a button  and javascript alert anchor url